# Contar quantas letras A tem numa frase em Dart

Tags: dart

O exercício proposto é simplesmente contar em uma frase qualquer, quantas letras A contém na mesma e qual a primeira e última vez que a letra A aparece na frase em Dart. Existe alguma classe ou método para ser resolvida a questão?

Comment: Uma dica para quando for criar um pergunta onde você já tem a resposta: Crie a pergunta apenas com o conteúdo da pergunta em sí. E depois responda a sua própria pergunta com o conteúdo referente. Assim daqui 2 dias você pode marcar sua pergunta como aceita, caso ninguém apareça com uma solução melhor.

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro obrigado pela dica. Já fiz e assim que que completar o processo de 2 dias excluo o post original

Comment: Não é necessário excluir nada, basta [edit]. No entanto o problema da sua pergunta não foi o código nela, foi falar de posição e de contar letras ao mesmo tempo. Não era necessário refazer a pergunta, bastava apenas [edit] e colocar a parte principal (que é a do titulo, contagem) removendo a parte sobre posição (que é algo que você já tinha resolvido e nem precisava misturar isso na pergunta).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você poderia usar o método [`Iterable<Match> allMatches(String string, [int start = 0])`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/Pattern/allMatches.html) (classe [`Pattern`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/Pattern-class.html)) que é herdado pela classe [`String`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/String-class.html) ficando assim:

```
void main() {
   const text = 'FOO BAR BAZ ZUZ';

   // Conta quantas letras A (em maiusculo), retorna 2
   print('A'.allMatches(text).length);

   // Conta quantas letras F (em maiusculo), retorna 1
   print('F'.allMatches(text).length);

   // Conta quantas letras Z (em maiusculo), retorna 3
   print('Z'.allMatches(text).length);
}
```

Pode conferir um exemplo online no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/T5BH2a)

Não pude comparar o seu código com `allMatches`, mas esse é um daqueles casos que talvez seja improvável que uma função mais rápida seja útil, já que o código da pergunta busca exclusivamente por letras, enquanto `allMatches` pode ser usado com strings mais complexas.

Talvez no futuro adicione um benchmark só para apresentar como comparativo.

**Observação:** Vale lembrar que letras acentuadas, dependendo da origem do *input*, podem ser de diferentes codificações, então é importante se atentar a isso na hora de desenvolver um programa.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 0):

Achei métodos para achar a posição da letra A na frase. Mas lendo a documentação, não achei nenhum método na classe String que consiga contar quantas letras A tem.
Então a melhor maneira que achei foi como visto no código a baixo.
Se alguém achar uma maneira mais simples ou um outro método em outra biblioteca agradeço pela ajuda. Se não, já fica uma forma de resolver isso.

```
void main() {
  String frase = 'Tudo depende do fluxo da flexibilidade do pulo do gafanhoto';
  print(frase);

  frase = frase.toUpperCase(); // Passa a frase para Caps para melhor trabalhar

  /* Contar quantas vezes aparece a letra A
  1º Pego o valor UTF-16 da letra A
  2º Transforma a frase em uma lista de UTF-16 e cria uma lista com todos 
     os valores encontrados referente a letra A em UTF-16
  3º Conta quantos valores existe na lista*/
  List letraA = 'A'.codeUnits; // 1º
  var quantosA = frase.codeUnits.where((x) => x == letraA[0]); // 2º
  print('Na frase tem ${quantosA.length} letras A.'); // 3º

  // Primeira letra A na frase
  int primeiroA = frase.indexOf('A') + 1;
  print('A primeira vez que o A aparece na frase é na $primeiroA\° posição.');

  // Última letra A na frase
  int ultimoA = frase.lastIndexOf('A') + 1;
  print('A última vez que o A aparece na frase é na $ultimoA\° posição.');
}
```